# Converting React ES6 class to functional component - what to use for private methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm converting a React ES6 class-style component to a functional component.  The one thing I'm slightly unsure of is how best to convert private class methods.  As far as I can tell, I should convert them to functions within the functional component's function, as they need to be there to access the component's state.  However, that presumably means that on each re-render, the function is going to get recreated:

**Before**

```
class Game extends React.Component {

    handleClick(i) { if (this.state.foo) { ... } }

}
```

**After**

```
function Game {

    function handleClick(i) { if (foo) { ... } }

}
```

Is this a problem performance-wise, and if so, is there any way to improve it?

Also, most guides I've read recommend assigning arrow functions to variables instead of just declaring functions, eg.

```
function Game {

    const handleClick = (i) => { if (foo) { ... } }

}
```

Is this purely stylistic, or is there another reason to use assigned arrow functions over regular nested function definitions?

Comment: [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that recommended elsewhere, and I've also seen advice that it's a waste of time and pointless to do it.  It seems a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions defined with either the `function` keyword or the arrow function syntax. It does not really make a difference in this case. However, with the arrow syntax, functions do not get hoisted, and that may cause the linter to report a warning if you use a function before it is defined.

> However, that presumably means that on each re-render, the function is
> going to get recreated

You are correct, if you define functions either way, they will get recreated on every re-render. Whether that's a problem or not will depend on your use case.

If you use such a function inside a `useEffect` callback and add it to its dependency array, the effect will re-run on every re-render (which may not be what you want). If you pass such a function as a `prop` to any child component(s), that component(s) will also re-render.

You can wrap the functions in question with `useCallback`, and any child components that receive these as `props` with `React.memo`. However, you are now trading the cost of re-rendering components for the cost of storing and comparing `props` (React will be doing this, not you).

So really, this depends on your app. If the component in question has a large component tree below it, going with `useCallback` and `React.memo` might be worth it.

Comment: So if anything, the `function` syntax is slightly safer because of hoisting?  Why is the arrow function syntax usually recommended then?

Comment: Its just a preference - its cleaner, more "modern" etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, arrow functions also get hoisted. `const` and `let` variables just can't be used before initialization.